# Is there ContainsStr equivalent for unicode strings?

Tags: string, delphi, unicode, delphi-2009

Today I was fixing up some warnings in our code and one of them is *"W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'"* in `ContainsStr` function.

After searching for a while for an equivalent of this function which takes two unicode strings as an argument I've decided to ask here. I would expect to find something like `ContainsWideStr` (for Delphi 2007 and lower) or `ContainsUnicodeStr` (for Delphi 2009+) but I couldn't find any of these.

I know I could just do something like this on my own:

```
function ContainsUnicodeStr(const AText, ASubText: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Pos(ASubText, AText) > 0;
end;
```

However, I would like to avoid duplication of code which is already in Delphi, but I simply do not know where.

Comment: If anywhere, it should be in the same unit that contains the ContainsStr function? Unless that is in some unit with Ansi in its name, then I would expect it to be in the strutils unit.

Comment: The routine described [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/de/System.StrUtils.ContainsStr) takes two Unicode strings.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I've got blocked and forgot to check this core unit! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`StrUtils.ContainsStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.StrUtils.ContainsStr) works with Unicode. But of course, [`AnsiStrings.ContainsStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.AnsiStrings.ContainsStr) does not.